# Trying to get the max from a group of aggregates

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here my schema: Exams(int students, int scores)
I am writing a SQL query to find the greatest spread between a student's score.

I have been able to generate a query that has the student id and their spread using this query:

```
select student, max(score) - min(score) from exams group by student;
```

Now this is where I am stumped. How do I get the maximum value of the spreads? More specifically, I don't really understand what to put in my select statement that would be outside my initial query.

Comment: You're looking for the `greatest spread between a student's score`. Isn't that what the query is returning? All students with their greatest spread? What would be your expected output? Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am trying to find the maximum spread. So if student A has scores 30 and 50 and B has scores 20 and 80, then B will have the highest spread since 20<60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a subquery:

```
select max(spread)
from (
    select student, max(score) - min(score) as spread from exams group by student
) x;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do. I keep getting an error though that no such column: spread exitst

Comment: @Ihatesyntaxerrors you sure you copied this exactly? the spread = part? you can try putting `max(score) - min(score) as spread` in the middle part instead, maybe my syntax doesn't work on your version of SQL.

Comment: Got it, I missed a character the first time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select student, max(score) - min(score) as SPREAD
from exams 
group by student
order by (max(score) - min(score)) DESC
```

This will at least show the results from highest to lowest